# How to get vuetify to display 'mdiSvg' icons?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuetify.js

Following the documentation here:
https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/icons
I setup my project exactly as described. 
Expected:
seeing an `<svg>` tag.
Actual:
I see an `<i>` tag (which causes issues with some settings on IE)
Here is a link to a reproduction:
https://codesandbox.io/embed/dialog-vuetify-bhs76

Answer (score 3):

This is the way I've been doing it. If you want, you can also set custom names for icons - which is very useful if you decide to change which icons you use:

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib';
import {
  mdiDelete
} from '@mdi/js';

Vue.use(Vuetify);

export default new Vuetify({
  icons: {
    iconfont: 'mdiSvg',
    values: {
      mdiDelete,
      // or give it a custom name:
      delete: mdiDelete,
    }
  },
});
```

Then in your v-icon component:

```
<v-icon>$mdiDelete</v-icon>
<v-icon>$delete</v-icon>
```

Answer (score 1):

you should install the right icon library from the [vuetify site](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/icons/#icons)
then import it on the vuetify plugin folder

```
export default new Vuetify({
  icons: {
    iconfont: 'mdiSvg', // 'mdi' || 'mdiSvg' || 'md' || 'fa' || 'fa4' || 'faSvg'
  },
})
```

least and last you should use the icon on the component

```
    <template>
      <div>
          <v-icon>{{mdiMenu}}</v-icon>
      </div>
    </template>

    <script>
    import { mdiMenu } from '@mdi/js'; 
    export default {
      data() {
        return {
            mdiMenu
        };
      }
    };
    </script>
```

you can find icons on this [material design site](https://materialdesignicons.com/)

Comment: I am looking for a way to do this globally not in each component. Thank you for the attempt